# Flag Module: "Never Flagged" Status

Tags: 7, flags

[Flag Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) is a very effective module for tagging entities which -  apparently - only handles two status: "flagged" and "unflagged", while  I need now to know if an entity was even been flagged before. So, 3 status:

- "never flagged"
- "flagged"
- "unflagged"

Which solution have we today in order to see if an entity has ever been flagged?

Comment: I haven't used flag in about a year, but last time I did I'm pretty sure it didn't have functionality like that. You might be able to query the `flag_counts` table and infer that entities missing from there have never been flagged. But I'm not sure if the module does maintenance on that table, it's a big module

Comment: This sounds like a unique use case. I doubt there is anything out there for you. Looks like building a custom module to keeps track in the DB when a flag is flagged maybe the only way.

Comment: When you unflag a count=1 record in flag_counts, flag module deletes that record. Having an "update count=0"  would have solved that. Good point,  @Clive

Comment: Ah right, I hadn't dived that far into it. Flag has a great API to be fair to it, @NoSssweat's suggestion of just creating a DB table in a custom module to track it yourself is a good one; you'd probably only need a single `db_merge` in a flag insert/update hook to make that happen

Comment: `mymodule_flag_flag($flag, $content_id, $account, $flagging) {
  // Do something in response to the flagging.
}`

Comment: Right, looks like there's no other solution then coding...

Comment: thanks for your precious support, @NoSssweat. Instead of unique, I  feel my case maybe be pretty popular. Example: you are using "Flag Module" for election voting. Would you be interested in knowing how many people did not vote? (so, never flagged)...

Comment: I highly doubt many people are doing that. If it was popular, there already be a contrib for that.

Answer (score 2):

IMO there ***is*** a solution without custom coding ... Below is a synopsis (to avoid writing a manual ...) of how to get this to work ...

## Step 1:

Create an additional flag, let's label it like "Ever flagged with `FlagX`" (whereas '`FlagX`' reflects the flag for which you want to know if the entity was ever flagged).

## Step 2:

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a rule like so:

- Rules Event: After entity (=node or user) is flagged with `FlagX`
- Rules Action: Flag an entity (= node or user), with parameter the flag "Ever flagged with `FlagX`"

Here is a sample of such rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format, adapt the machine name of both flags to fit your needs prior to importing it in your own site), for a flag used for flagging an entity of type "user":

```
{ "rules_set_the_ever_flagged_with_flagx_flag" : {
    "LABEL" : "Set the ever flagged with FlagX flag",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_flagx" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_flaguser" : {
          "flag" : "ever_flagged_with_flagx ",
          "user" : [ "flagged-user" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "flagging-user" ],
          "permission_check" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Step 3:

"*To know if an entity was ever been flagged before*" (as in your question), all you need to do now is to check for the entities that have been flagged with the "Ever flagged with `FlagX`" flag. Obviously, it should be straight forward to use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create an appropriate list of those entities (like users) for which the "Ever flagged with `FlagX`" flag is ***not yet*** set ... which would then be the actual answer to your question, i.e. the entities (like users) which were "**N**ever flagged with `FlagX`".

Comment: Interesting approach

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer: merci! Things don't always have to be complicated, right? And **K**eep **It** **S**uper **S**imple solutions are also easy to maintain, upgrade, etc, no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens plan is cool! Unfortunately, we cannot have that 3rd status in the flag link, though. IMO, the one who's editing a question  should not think at actual answer...

Comment: @augusto: I don't understand your last comment. I'm not talking about a "3rd status". Instead my answer, in step one, is about an **additional** flag. Also, I don't understand  your"*the one who's editing a question should not think at actual answer*". So can you try again to better explain your last comment?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I need a 3rd status, aside the true/false status already handled by Flag. Also, don't edit questions  you can't understand (this sounds rude, while I don't want to ... sorry). Thanks for your time spent on this

Comment: @augusto : note that I just performed a rollback of your question (which I think I "do" understand). Should you want to reuse anything that was included in my revision 2 of it: go ahead (no credits due). FYI: the "Drupal 7" part of your (restored) title is redundant, every question on Drupal.SE is ... about Drupal. and the "7" is what is also in the tag you used for it. So please consider at least removing that part from your title.

Answer (score 1):

Add a term reference field to a taxonomy vocabulary that lists the three options.

By default, the field saves as "not flagged", on flag, rules changes it to "flagged" and on unflag, rules changes it to "unflagged".

Add some conditions so the field isn't changed unnecessarily. I never feel bad about adding fields for site features.

Comment: That's indeed another way to reach your goal ...

Comment: pierre's answer is more detailed. mind putting some details?

Comment: It's just a taxonomy field with a default of "not flagged" that gets changed by rules when the node is flagged or unflagged. Event: Flag > Action: Taxonomy term: "flagged". And another.. Event: Unflag > Action: Taxonomy term: "unflagged". The key here is that while we still use the flag module, this extra field shows the difference between "not flagged' (the default on node creation) and "unflagged" in an easy way.